# Own Cydia App crash

Tags: iphone, xcode, cydia

I build a simple Iphone App (Hello World) and pack it to a deb with iDeb. In the Simulator it work (why not is only Hello World on a View). I upload it on MyRepoSpace but when I try to download it came so error Code:

> “Subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1″
>
> “sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error coda (1)”

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

The deb package doesn't sound like it's been packaged correctly.

File structure is like this, right?

```
-DebName < Applications < MyApp.app
           DEBIAN < control
```

Command to create .deb:

```
dpkg-deb -b DebName outputfile.deb
```

Comment: No because iDeb pack it correctly. I upload some Thems and must only pack it to a .zip and upload it.